# Everything in a simple Express.js app is acting as a link to a single view. What's going on?

Tags: node.js, routes, view, express, rendering

I built a really simple multi-page Express.js app for a client with some forms. But now after I've applied a bunch of CSS to it and been getting it ready to deliver, I've been getting some bizarre behavior on localhost. When I push the site up, everything acts as a link to the "About Us" view. When I click on an image, when I click on an input field in the "Contact Us" form, even  tagged text, it all redirects me to the "About Us" view.

Here's my config settings:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'botheredbybronies' }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.favicon(__dirname + '/public/images/aquifavicon1.svg'));
});

app.configure('development', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function(){
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});
```

And here's the route in question, nothing special about it:

```
app.get('/about', function (req, res, next) {
res.render('about', {title: 'About Aqui'});
});
```

I just want to understand what is causing this. If you have any ideas, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the problem is with the pages you're serving (i.e. everything turns into a link).

Either you have some global `onClick` handler on your page, or (more likely) some `<a href="...">` tag was not closed (turning everything until the end of the page or the next `<a href="...">` link into a link).

You can check it in Chrome by selecting "Inspect element" from the text unexpectedly acting as a link and checking for `onClick` event listeners or `<a href="...">` elements up in the DOM tree.

It is hard to say anything more than that without looking at the rendered page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply penartur.

I've done all HTML structure here in Jade, and links are done as `a(href='/url', title='name') NAME`. Is there a more explicit way to escape a link in Jade?

Comment: Open a webpage with such a problem you're experiencing in Chrome; right-click on any element with such behavior (acts as a link despite not being one), select the "Inspect Element" option from the context menu and check whether there are any `<a href="...">` elements up in the DOM tree.

Comment: Got it. I had a single element one space too many (making it a child element) in the layout.jade file. Moving that fixed it immediately.